# understanding get() behavior in someone else's code

Tags: python

I am looking at this [python code for EPGReader](https://bitbucket.org/mfabrik/epgreader/src/a60a0799b4cc/epg_stream_decoder.py) and am trying to understand how `reader = self.PIDHandlers.get(headers.PID, None)`works. What does the `get` return?

So, `PIDHandlers` is `dict` is made up of the `TSSectionReader` class and that calls the `SDTSectionContainer` class. Have I understood this correctly?

My goal is to add code to process [PAT tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) and I am forcing myself to understand someone else's code instead of copping out and writing my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PIDHandlers` is a `dict`, yes. The `get` call returns `PIDHandlers[headers.PID]` if `headers.PID` is in `PIDHandlers.keys()`, or `None` otherwise.

`get` is just a `dict` access which doesn't throw `KeyError`, instead returning the given default.